# Libgdx moving a body in sequence

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d-games

How can I move a body (box2d) to different points in an order. Like first it moves to 100,200 then to 200, 450 and so on? I've tried actions(and actor) but I can't get the point where the body is heading (the position of MoveToAction), I need it to draw the character(body) at different sides. And I don't need to control it, just it moves itself... Also, I tried to do it in render, but it always repeats

Comment: are you using box2d? just rendering sprites? gonna use collision? are you using any physics engine? Gonna use any pathfinding algorithms(Dijkstra's, A* search,by Sample)?

Comment: Yes, I am using box2d and using collisions, I need it. What do you mean about pathfinding algorithms?

Comment: To achieve what you want, entities that move from point to point by 'em self you need to create a A.I. that handle the actions, for instance to move one entity from vector1 to vector2 you need a pathfinding algorithm that will do the calculations to find a path or if the destinations is even possible to reach, mostly people use the A* algorithm on games  for that, because it's light on processing with a very good result. You must build a Entity manager, entity notifications and a entity scheduler before building your A.I. as well..

Comment: No, I just need to do a void method as an action